# Where is publish_actions in facebook review page?

Tags: facebook

I am newer to make app using facebook iOS SDK.
My app need publish_actions to publish comment to user feed.
But I could not find the publish_actions from the list at review page to add.
I check the publish_pages, but I understood this permission is not used for user feed.
How can I add publish_actions for review item?
[image: Facebook Review]

I noticed that Facebook Permissons Reference Page(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions) dose not have publish_actions item anymore.

Comment: what´s your code to publish a comment to a user feed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#4-24-2018:

> Facebook Login
>
> - The `publish_actions` permission has been removed.

---

Facebook is making a lot of changes currently, due to the Cambridge Analytica “scandal”.

Some of the stuff that is currently disabled might return in one form or another; but this sounds like it might be final - and that publishing in the name of a user via API is simply not possible any more.

---

There’s also already a bug report regarding this, https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1677448822335592/ - but the response from Facebook sounds like it might actually be gone for good.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! That's too bad.. I need to remove publish function.

Comment: man that blows. do you know how will we upload content to Facebook? our app used to upload a video and then we saved then link in our DB how will we go about it now?

Comment: @LukeCarelsen they say they are working on a replacement, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#live-api-4-24 _“In the coming weeks, a new permission model that allows apps to publish Videos to their User's Groups and Timelines will be announced.”_