# Can Facebook's Unity plugin be used to post to a product page?

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine

I'd like to add Facebook sharing to a Unity app. The basic idea is to:

1. Create a Facebook page for the app.
2. Enable the users of the app to post screenshots from inside the app **onto the apps facebook page**.

The idea behind it is to have access to all posted screenshots by collecting them on the apps facebook page. Can this be done using Facebooks Unity plugin?
If yes:

- Does the user first need to "befriend" (join) the apps Facebook page?
- Does the app need to go through Facebooks review process?
- If a user posts a screenhot to the apps page, is the screenshot then also visible on the users facebook feed or only on the apps facebook page?

Considering the nature of the questions it's obvious that I ain't a Facebook user. So your help is very appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: [Facebook just removed the permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50062703/) that allows to post anything, anywhere in the name of the user, so posting like this via API will not be possible any more.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for the comment. Can it be done somehow else? (i.e. without API?) I kinda don't get it: What's the use of Facebooks plugin if we can't publish something? I don't see much usecases...

Comment: Plugins and API are two different things. And Facebook is limiting what was possible via API, because it got abused too much. You can check if you can call any of the dialogs that allow the user to perform a share manually; although I don’t think you can specify a page as target upfront, if anything, the users would have to type the page name themselves.